# Rails 5: set daily invitation limit with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

Recently I installed `devise_invitable` and now I would like to add a daily `invitation_limit`.

I know that I can make some configurations to `devise_invitable` in my `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

Currently my devise.rb file looks like this:

`config.invitation_limit = 5`

I thinking of a way to set a daily limit, probably something like this:

```
  config.invitation_limit = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly hacky perhaps but you could use the existing mechanisms for limiting invitations and just reset them each day.

By default invitable adds an `invitation_limit` column to users which records the number of invitations they have left. If you had an scheduled task to reset that each day to however many invitations you want to allow per day then it would 'just work' I think.

The less hacky way would be to add your own `invitation_daily_limit` to users and to check that in an overridden [`has_invitations_left?`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/db250393fe48cb34f54ae8e52dcb5cf1e7e1a2e3/lib/devise_invitable/inviter.rb#L15) method on User and decrement it in [`decrement_invitation_limit!`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/db250393fe48cb34f54ae8e52dcb5cf1e7e1a2e3/lib/devise_invitable/inviter.rb#L28) too.

You can see those methods in devise_invitable: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/inviter.rb.

You'd still need to do something to reset the daily limit though and that'd probably be easiest with a scheduled task.